# Faster way to load data from MongoDB cursor to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, performance, dataframe

I'm trying to analyse a facebook conversation with 150k messages (~40MB) that I stored into MongoDB. I noticed that taking the data from MongoDB to pandas was long (it takes ~25s) and I found that `data = [msg for msg in cursor]` is the step that's slowing the process.

Is there a faster way to transform the MongoDB cursor to a DataFrame?

Here is some of my code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd

connection = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
database = connection[DBS_NAME]
messages = database['messages']
cursor = messages.find(projection=FIELDS)
data = [msg for msg in cursor]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I also could replace this step by `df = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))` or `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor)` but it still takes 25s.

I'm saying it's slow because I want to make graphs of who sent the most messages and put them in a website. I make the analysis in Python with Flask and I transfer a json containing my processed data to javascript. That way, everytime you enter the site, it makes the data processing and I don't want it to take 25s before showing the graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the aggregation in mongodb instead of flask

You can delegate the heavy lifting to mongodb, bringing data out of mongodb takes I/O and you cant reduce to sub seconds unless your client side and mongo servers are capable of handling 40MB/Sec.

```
db.getCollection('COLLECTION').aggregate([{$sortByCount: "$FIELD11"}, {$limit : 10}])
```

This runs in 0.6 secs with ~300k records